# Update Gridview with data from radio button list on button click

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview

Good Day!

I'm having a hard time with my Gridview. I'm using C#.net and sql server. I want to update my gridview rows with the data from the column of radio button list with a button outside gridview. Here's my gridview;

[image]

I want to update column[rating] with the selected value from radio button list on a single button click.

Currently, I update the gridview column rating by clicking the rate button and getting the rating value from the dropdown list above the gridview.

Now, I'm wondering if there's a way to do it on one click and get it's value from the radio button list inside the gridview. My gridview code is here;

```
<p>
                <asp:GridView ID="GridView1" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="False" onrowcommand="delete_enroll" 
                    DataSourceID="training" Width="826px" AllowPaging="True" Visible="False" 
                    style="text-align: center">
                    <Columns>
                        <asp:ButtonField ButtonType="Button" CommandName="deleterow" Text="CANCEL" />
                        <asp:ButtonField ButtonType="Button" CommandName="RATE" Text="RATE" />
                        <asp:BoundField DataField="Training_id" HeaderText="Training_id" 
                            SortExpression="Training_id" />
                        <asp:BoundField DataField="User_id" HeaderText="User_id" 
                            SortExpression="User_id" />
                        <asp:BoundField DataField="User_name" HeaderText="User_name" 
                            SortExpression="User_name" />
                        <asp:BoundField DataField="Date_enrolled" HeaderText="Date_enrolled" 
                            SortExpression="Date_enrolled" />
                        <asp:BoundField DataField="Rating" HeaderText="Rating" 
                            SortExpression="Rating" />

                            <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Rate">
                                <ItemTemplate>
                                    <asp:RadioButtonList ID="RadioButtonList1" runat="server">
                                        <asp:ListItem Text="Passed" Value="Passed"></asp:ListItem>
                                        <asp:ListItem Text="Failed" Value="Failed"></asp:ListItem>
                                    </asp:RadioButtonList>
                                </ItemTemplate>
                            </asp:TemplateField>

                    </Columns>
                </asp:GridView>
            </p>
```

Any help would be appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: You want to update the `Rating` column when user clicks on `Rate` button or let user select radio button in all the rows and update them all with a button present outside?

Comment: I want to let user select radio button in all the rows and update them all with a button present outside. Is that possible?

Comment: Yes it is is possible you just have to disable postback on radiobutton and browse all your gridview lines after click on save button outside of the grid view.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can loop through the rows of gridview in you button click event handler and update the respective row like this:-

```
protected void btnUpdate_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    foreach (GridViewRow row in GridView1.Rows)
    {
        RadioButtonList RadioButtonList1 = row.FindControl("RadioButto nList1") 
                                               as RadioButtonList;
        row.Cells[6].Text = RadioButtonList1.SelectedValue;
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your help. I will try it.

Comment: Also, I would like to know how can I get the value of Training_id and user_id so I can use it on my Where clause in my SQL statement.

Comment: After trying, I got it now. Thanks for your help!